# Error assigning variable type

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

I'm afraid I'm not sure if this is a question about **WebStorm**, **Angular2** or **Typescript**.

I have an Angular2 build set up and am using WebStorm 2016.1.2 to edit with. One of my components gets a reference to a DOM element using a simple `document.getElementById('some-el');` and passes this to a service method:

```
calc(el:HTMLElement){
    this.height = el.offsetHeight;
    this.width = el.offsetWidth;

    let span:HTMLElement = el.querySelector("span");
    this.pos = span.offsetTop - span.offsetHeight;
}
```

Everything works fine and I don't get any errors in the browser but I do get an error in WebStorm linked to `el.querySelector("span");`

The error says: **`Initializer type Element is not assignable to variable type HTMLElement`**

I don't know if this a problem with WebStorm or if I am actually typing things wrong. If I set the type of `span` to `Element` the error disappears but then the `offsetTop` and `offsetHeight` are highlighted as incorrect??

As the actual build doesn't seem to suffer when I run it I just wonder if this is something in my code I need to fix or something in my editor that I can ignore?

Cheers for your help

Comment: https://github.com/cloud9ide/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts#L2410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to cast it:

```
calc(el:HTMLElement){
    this.height = el.offsetHeight;
    this.width = el.offsetWidth;

    let span:HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> el.querySelector("span");
    this.pos = span.offsetTop - span.offsetHeight;
}
```

Or you can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
let span:HTMLElement = el.querySelector("span") as HTMLElement;
```

What happens is that `querySelector` returns `Element` and not `HTMLElement` as you declared the type of `span` to be.  But you can tell the compiler to "trust you" that you know that it's indeed an `HTMLElement`.

You can also use `HTMLSpanElement` instead of the `HTMLElement` which is more specific, just like `HTMLElement` is more specific than `Element` (that's why when you changed it to `Element` the `offsetTop` and `offsetHeight` weren't available).

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I was a Flash developer for years and this is exactly how you do it in AS3. Ah well, live and learn. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `<HTMLElement> obj` and `obj as HTMLElement` are _both_ type-assertions, there is no such thing as a type-_cast_ in TypeScript. Also, AFAIK, the latter is now the preferred syntax, as the former is ambiguous in `.tsx` context.